# Git says "Can't commit. You are not on the correct branch" even though I am?

Tags: git, github

I created a new branch, did some work and went to commit it (first commit on this branch) only to get the error:

> Execution of target "commit" failed for the following reason: You are not on the correct branch.

Would anyone know why this has occurred and if it can be fixed?

Git status:

```
# On branch my_branch
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified: myfile.php
#
```

Comment: Can you post your `git status` here?

Comment: Upvoted for coming up with one I've never ever seen.

Comment: @PhilipTzou I've added it above. Note the branch in the status is correct.

Comment: What is your exact commit command line? Do you have any local hooks?

Comment: What does `ls .git/hooks` show?

Comment: For what it's worth, Git does not contain that error message anywhere. It is not coming from Git at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No exactly an answer, but I switched to the same branch and it works now. Weird.